# Incorrect behavior of image undistortion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, projection

I'm trying to create a program that receives a photograph of a surface from a certain angle and position, and generates an image of what an isometric projection of the plane would look like. For example, given a photo of a checkerboard

[image]

and information about the positioning and properties of the camera, it could reconstruct a section of the undistorted pattern

[image]

My approach has been divided into two parts. The first part is to create four rays, coming from the camera, following the four corners of its field of view. I compute where these rays intersect with the plane, to form the quadrangle of the area of the plane that the camera can see, like this:

[image]

The second part is to render an isomorphic projection of the plane with the textured quadrangle. I divide the quadrangle into two triangles, then for each pixel on the rendering, I convert the cartesian coordinates into barymetric coordinates relative to each triangle, then convert it back into cartesian coordinates relative to a corresponding triangle that consumes half of the photograph, so that I can sample a color.

(I am aware that this could be done more efficiently with OpenGL, but I would like to not use it for logistical reasons. I am also aware that the quality will be affected by lack of interpolation, that does not matter for this task.)

I am testing the program with some data, but the rendering does not occur as intended. Here is the photograph:

[image]

And here is the program output:

[image]

I believe that the problem is occurring in the quadrangle rendering, because I have graphed the projected vertices, and they appear to be correct:

[image]

I am by no means an expert in computer graphics, so I would very much appreciate if someone had any idea what would cause this problem. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class ImageProjector {

    private static final EquationSystem ground = new EquationSystem(0, 1, 0, 0);

    private double fov;
    private double aspectRatio;
    private vec3d position;
    private double xAngle;
    private double yAngle;
    private double zAngle;

    public ImageProjector(double fov, double aspectRatio, vec3d position, double xAngle, double yAngle, double zAngle) {
        this.fov = fov;
        this.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
        this.position = position;
        this.xAngle = xAngle;
        this.yAngle = yAngle;
        this.zAngle = zAngle;
    }

    public vec3d[] computeVertices() {
        return new vec3d[] {
                computeVertex(1, 1),
                computeVertex(1, -1),
                computeVertex(-1, -1),
                computeVertex(-1, 1)
        };
    }

    private vec3d computeVertex(int horizCoef, int vertCoef) {
        vec3d p2 = new vec3d(tan(fov / 2) * horizCoef, tan((fov / 2) / aspectRatio) * vertCoef, 1);
        p2 = p2.rotateXAxis(xAngle);
        p2 = p2.rotateYAxis(yAngle);
        p2 = p2.rotateZAxis(zAngle);
        if (p2.y > 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("sky is visible to camera: " + p2);
        }
        p2 = p2.plus(position);
        //System.out.println("passing through " + p2);
        EquationSystem line = new LineBuilder(position, p2).build();
        return new vec3d(line.add(ground).solveVariables());
    }


}


public class barypoint {

    public barypoint(double u, double v, double w) {
        this.u = u;
        this.v = v;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public final double u;
    public final double v;
    public final double w;

    public barypoint(vec2d p, vec2d a, vec2d b, vec2d c) {
        vec2d v0 = b.minus(a);
        vec2d v1 = c.minus(a);
        vec2d v2 = p.minus(a);
        double d00 = v0.dotProduct(v0);
        double d01 = v0.dotProduct(v1);
        double d11 = v1.dotProduct(v1);
        double d20 = v2.dotProduct(v0);
        double d21 = v2.dotProduct(v1);
        double denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01;
        v = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom;
        w = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom;
        u = 1.0 - v - w;
    }

    public barypoint(vec2d p, Triangle triangle) {
        this(p, triangle.a, triangle.b, triangle.c);
    }

    public vec2d toCartesian(vec2d a, vec2d b, vec2d c) {
        return new vec2d(
                u * a.x + v * b.x + w * c.x,
                u * a.y + v * b.y + w * c.y
        );
    }

    public vec2d toCartesian(Triangle triangle) {
        return toCartesian(triangle.a, triangle.b, triangle.c);
    }

}


public class ImageTransposer {

    private BufferedImage source;
    private BufferedImage receiver;

    public ImageTransposer(BufferedImage source, BufferedImage receiver) {
        this.source = source;
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public void transpose(Triangle sourceCoords, Triangle receiverCoords) {
        int xMin = (int) Double.min(Double.min(receiverCoords.a.x, receiverCoords.b.x), receiverCoords.c.x);
        int xMax = (int) Double.max(Double.max(receiverCoords.a.x, receiverCoords.b.x), receiverCoords.c.x);
        int yMin = (int) Double.min(Double.min(receiverCoords.a.y, receiverCoords.b.y), receiverCoords.c.y);
        int yMax = (int) Double.max(Double.max(receiverCoords.a.y, receiverCoords.b.y), receiverCoords.c.y);
        for (int x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++) {
            for (int y = yMin; y <= yMax; y++) {
                vec2d p = new vec2d(x, y);
                if (receiverCoords.contains(p) && p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0 && p.x < receiver.getWidth() && y < receiver.getHeight()) {
                    barypoint bary = new barypoint(p, receiverCoords);
                    vec2d sp = bary.toCartesian(sourceCoords);
                    if (sp.x >= 0 && sp.y >= 0 && sp.x < source.getWidth() && sp.y < source.getHeight()) {
                        receiver.setRGB(x, y, source.getRGB((int) sp.x, (int) sp.y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public class ProjectionRenderer {

    private String imagePath;
    private BufferedImage mat;
    private vec3d[] vertices;
    private vec2d pos;
    private double scale;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public boolean error = false;

    public ProjectionRenderer(String image, BufferedImage mat, vec3d[] vertices, vec3d pos, double scale, int width, int height) {
        this.imagePath = image;
        this.mat = mat;
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.pos = new vec2d(pos.x, pos.z);
        this.scale = scale;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

            vec2d[] transVerts = Arrays.stream(vertices)
                    .map(v -> new vec2d(v.x, v.z))
                    .map(v -> v.minus(pos))
                    .map(v -> v.multiply(scale))
                    .map(v -> v.plus(new vec2d(mat.getWidth() / 2, mat.getHeight() / 2)))
                    // this fixes the image being upside down
                    .map(v -> new vec2d(v.x, mat.getHeight() / 2 + (mat.getHeight() / 2 - v.y)))
                    .toArray(vec2d[]::new);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(transVerts));

            Triangle sourceTri1 = new Triangle(
                    new vec2d(0, 0),
                    new vec2d(image.getWidth(), 0),
                    new vec2d(0, image.getHeight())
            );
            Triangle sourceTri2 = new Triangle(
                    new vec2d(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()),
                    new vec2d(0, image.getHeight()),
                    new vec2d(image.getWidth(), 0)
            );
            Triangle destTri1 = new Triangle(
                    transVerts[3],
                    transVerts[0],
                    transVerts[2]
            );
            Triangle destTri2 = new Triangle(
                    transVerts[1],
                    transVerts[2],
                    transVerts[0]
            );

            ImageTransposer transposer = new ImageTransposer(image, mat);
            System.out.println("transposing " + sourceTri1 + " -> " + destTri1);
            transposer.transpose(sourceTri1, destTri1);
            System.out.println("transposing " + sourceTri2 + " -> " + destTri2);
            transposer.transpose(sourceTri2, destTri2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because your `transpose` function works entirely with 2D co-ordinates, therefore it cannot compensate for the image distortion resulting from 3D perspective. You have effectively implemented a 2D [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). Parallel lines remain parallel, which they do not under a 3D perspective transform. If you draw a straight line between two points on your triangle, you can linearly interpolate between them by linearly interpolating the barycentric co-ordinates, and vice versa.

To take Z into account, you can keep the barycentric co-ordinate approach, but provide a Z co-ordinate for each point in `sourceCoords`. The trick is to interpolate between 1/Z values (which *can* be linearly interpolated in a perspective image) instead of interpolating Z itself. So instead of interpolating what are effectively the texture co-ordinates for each point, interpolate the texture co-ordinate divided by Z, along with inverse Z, and interpolate all of those using your barycentric system. Then divide by inverse Z before doing your texture lookup to get texture co-ordinates back.

You could do that like this (assume a b c contain an extra z co-ordinate giving distance from camera):

```
public vec3d toCartesianInvZ(vec3d a, vec3d b, vec3d c) {
    // put some asserts in to check for z = 0 to avoid div by zero
    return new vec3d(
            u * a.x/a.z + v * b.x/b.z + w * c.x/c.z,
            u * a.y/a.z + v * b.y/b.z + w * c.y/c.z,
            u * 1/a.z + v * 1/b.z + w * 1/c.z
    );
}
```

(You could obviously speed up/simplify this by pre-computing all those divides and storing in `sourceCoords`, and just doing regular barycentric interpolation in 3D)

Then after you call it in `transpose`, divide by inv Z to get the texture co-ords back:

```
vec3d spInvZ = bary.toCartesianInvZ(sourceCoords);
vec2d sp = new vec2d(spInvZ.x / spInvZ.z, spInvZ.y / spInvZ.z);
```

etc. The Z co-ordinate that you need is the distance of the point in 3D space from the camera position, in the direction the camera is pointing. You can compute it with a dot product if you aren't getting it some other way:

```
float z = point.subtract(camera_pos).dot(camera_direction);
```

etc